# What type to use to hold both reversed and normal range in rust?

Tags: rust

I want to create either a forward iterator or a reverse iterator based on a flag. However, a reversed range has a different type, meaning that I cannot store it as the same variable.

A minimal example of the kind of thing I'm trying to do is as follows:

```rust
fn iterate_in_direction(start_index: usize, length: usize, reversed: bool) {
    // this doesn't compile because the types in the different branches don't match
    let index_iterator;
    if reversed {
        // this is a Rev<Range<usize>>
        index_iterator = (0..start_index).rev();
    } else {
        // this is just a Range<usize>
        index_iterator = start_index..length;
    }

    for i in index_iterator {
        // in the real world, we do something more complex, so duplicating this loop in the different branches of the if statement isn't a good solution
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

How can I convert both a `Rev<Range<usize>>` and a `Range<usize>` to the same type?